# Access HttpContext.Current.Session in Nancy Module

Tags: asp.net, nancy

I've read a lot of answers saying to just use the built-in Nancy Session/User object, but this isn't an option in my case.

Using WCF I was able to access the ASP.Net `Session["SomethingStuffedIntoSessionFromAWebForm"]` by enabling `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` in the `web.config` (other stuff had to been done too, probably), but I can't seem to figure out how to get a handle on the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` (or anything else in the current context) from within a Nancy module.

My 1st thought was to inject it in the bootstrapper but I can't even get a handle on the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` there either. Any ideas?

*Edit*

I ended up just stuffing an encrypted version of my desired session object into a cookie upstream and checking/validating against it in the module's BeforePipeline... not too crazy about this approach, but it suits my needs for now.

As far as I can tell, when a Nancy module handles a request, it bypasses the Asp.Net pipeline, so while I actually do have access to `HttpContext.Current`, `Session` is not populated.

Comment: Which hosting package are you using?

Comment: I'm curious why ASP session, and not the Nancy own session management.

Comment: Asp.Net hosting package. I don't have access to other parts of the program to implement the nancy way-of-things and I cannot modify our existing user store (so no guid for the built-in auth packages). I ended up rolling my own token-esque solution, although I don't feel really good about it... basically I'm encrypting what I need elseware in a cookie and checking that in the before pipeline on the module. I would really be interested in how to get access to the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session in a nancy module though.

Comment: I appreciate the separation of concerns in order to get nancy hosted anywhere/self-hosted, but I think this limitation would be a show-stopper in a lot of shops as a drop-in replacement for WCF/WebApi endpoints.

Comment: As @System.Web.HttpContext.Current@ should be accessible, this means that your problem is actually a session not being populated. Is asp.net session state management enabled in web.config? Please, refine the question with all possible information - what you have tried, what exactly doesn't work, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit IRequiresSessionState to enable Asp.net Session.

public class NancyAspHttpRequestHandler 
: NancyHttpRequestHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

}

and use NancyAspHttpRequestHandler in handler registration, this can be possible using Nancy.AspNet hosting.

This will solve the problem